# Spark 3.3.0 not honoring my schema nullability in Java

Tags: csv, apache-spark, schema

I'm using Spark 3.3.0 with Java 11. I'm reading a single-column CSV file of IDs. I want to manually set the schema. What could be simpler? I use:

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(List.of(
    DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, false)))
```

Notice that I indicate `false` for the nullability.

I read the file:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "false")
    .schema(schema).load("path/to/file.csv")
df.printSchema();
```

Here's the schema it prints:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

What? Didn't I just tell Spark that the `id` columns should *not* be nullable? What did I do wrong to screw up this most basic of operations?

Comment: So can you refute the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Time in the field reveals that Spark csv processing / API does not have data source level support for null constraints. You get it all with null in schema.

I noted this at the outset and read it also on SO.

Comment: Exactly. What differentiates null from an empty cell? If you want nullable fields in the dataframe, use a file format that supports it like JSON or Parquet.

Comment: "If you want nullable fields in the dataframe …" OneCricketeer it's interesting that you are arguing about why I should be happy with non-nullability and not want nullability, when the whole point of the question is that I am _not_ wanting nullability, but Spark is forcing the schema to be nullable. And any argument about the file format is orthogonal: I should be able to specify nullability in the scheme regardless of what file format is used. Moreover specifying `nullable = false` should actually _help_ spark know how to handle blank CSV cells. So none of that comment addresses my question.